# What is the proper way to sweep over all configs in an external config group?

Tags: fb-hydra

I want to store a config group in an external package and then sweep across all configs in that group with a hydra multirun call using `glob(*)`, but the `glob(*)` doesn't seem to find the available configs.

Specifically, suppose I have some .yaml settings at the root of an external python package called `hydra_demo`.

```
hydra_demo
├── __init__.py
└── hyper_param_settings
    ├── v1.yaml
    ├── v2.yaml
```

My primary config file adds the package to the searchpath:

```yaml
hydra:
  searchpath:
    - pkg://hydra_demo
```

As expected, I can use command-line override to use either config in the config group:

```sh
$ python experiments/main.py '+hyper_param_settings@=v1'
param=111
```

```sh
$ python experiments/main.py '+hyper_param_settings@=v2'
param=222
```

Also, as expected, if I don't specify a config from the group, it lists out the two options:

```sh
$ python experiments/main.py '+hyper_param_settings@='
In 'config': Could not find 'hyper_param_settings/'

Available options in 'hyper_param_settings':
        v1
        v2
Config search path:
        provider=hydra, path=pkg://hydra.conf
        provider=main, path=file:///path/to/experiments
        provider=hydra.searchpath in main, path=pkg://hydra_demo
        provider=schema, path=structured://

Set the environment variable HYDRA_FULL_ERROR=1 for a complete stack trace.
```

However, using glob to run all options doesn't work as I would have expected:

```sh
$ python experiments/main.py '+hyper_param_settings@=glob(*)' -m
[2021-12-30 22:42:53,656][HYDRA] Launching 0 jobs locally
```

But if I copy the `hyper_param_settings` folder from the package into the folder where the primary config is, I do get the expected behavior (but without achieving my goal of having the config groups in a separate package):

```sh
$ python experiments/main.py '+hyper_param_settings@=glob(*)' -m
[2021-12-30 22:43:17,342][HYDRA] Launching 2 jobs locally
[2021-12-30 22:43:17,342][HYDRA]        #0 : +hyper_param_settings@=v1
param=111
[2021-12-30 22:43:17,430][HYDRA]        #1 : +hyper_param_settings@=v2
param=222
```

Can anyone spot where I'm misunderstanding hydra?

Comment: I can reproduce the behavior from your example. Seems like a bug.

Comment: I've opened a bug report: https://github.com/facebookresearch/hydra/issues/1942